# ReactJS Stopwatch, how to handle localstorage data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have component where i count time (Stopwatch). everything is working fine. Start, stop of the clock reset. I wanted to add functionality that when i stop clock (`handleTimerStop`) set current state to localstorage in case if i close browser and want to return and want to start where i left clock paused. So when i stop clock items are setup to localstorage but when i want to restart clock it doesn't take data from local storage but start from scratch. Could you please help? also it will be great if someone can optimsie my code becasue i feel it can be done better.

thanks

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Timer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timerStarted: false,
      timerStopped: true,
      hours: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      seconds: 0
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("sec") === null) {
      this.setState({
        seconds: localStorage.getItem("sec")
      });
    }
    if (!localStorage.getItem("min") === null) {
      this.setState({
        seconds: localStorage.getItem("min")
      });
    }
    if (!localStorage.getItem("hour") === null) {
      this.setState({
        seconds: localStorage.getItem("hours")
      });
    }
  }

  handleTimerStart = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (localStorage.getItem("sec") === null) {
      this.setState({
        seconds: 0
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        seconds: localStorage.getItem("sec")
      });
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("min") === null) {
      this.setState({
        minutes: 0
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        minutes: localStorage.getItem("min")
      });
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("hour") === null) {
      this.setState({
        hours: 0
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        hours: localStorage.getItem("hour")
      });
    }

    if (this.state.timerStopped) {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({ timerStarted: true, timerStopped: false });
        if (this.state.timerStarted) {
          if (this.state.seconds >= 60) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              minutes: prevState.minutes + 1,
              seconds: localStorage.getItem("sec")
            }));
          }
          if (this.state.minutes >= 60) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              hours: prevState.hours + 1,
              minutes: localStorage.getItem("min"),
              seconds: localStorage.getItem("sec")
            }));
          }
          this.setState(prevState => ({ seconds: prevState.seconds + 1 }));
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  };

  handleTimerStop = () => {
    this.setState({ timerStarted: false, timerStopped: true });
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    localStorage.setItem("sec", this.state.seconds);
    localStorage.setItem("min", this.state.minutes);
    localStorage.setItem("hour", this.state.hours);
  };

  handelResetTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerStarted: false,
      timerStopped: true,
      hours: 0,
      minutes: 0,
      seconds: 0
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h2 className="text-center"> React Based Timer </h2>
        <div className="timer-container">
          <div className="current-timer">
            {this.state.hours +
              ":" +
              this.state.minutes +
              ":" +
              this.state.seconds}
          </div>
          <div className="timer-controls">
            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleTimerStart}>
              Start Timer
            </button>
            <button className="btn btn-alert" onClick={this.handleTimerStop}>
              Stop Timer
            </button>
            <button className="btn btn-info"> Capture Time </button>
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handelResetTimer}>
              {" "}
              Reset!{" "}
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These comparations are your problem.

```
!null === null or !'23' === null ... false always.



if (!localStorage.getItem("sec") === null) {
  this.setState({
    seconds: localStorage.getItem("sec")
  });
}
if (!localStorage.getItem("min") === null) {
  this.setState({
    seconds: localStorage.getItem("min")
  });
}
if (!localStorage.getItem("hour") === null) {
  this.setState({
    seconds: localStorage.getItem("hours")
  });
}
```

Comment: can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This ain't an answer to your concrete question, but imo. a better approach at your code

This implementation is

- independant of the render interval,
- only writes to localStorage when you start/stop/reset it
- and is not getting out of sync (even if it does not get rendered at all)

.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Timer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    try {
      this.state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.props.localStorage));
    } catch (error) {}

    if (!this.state) {
      this.state = this.saveChanges({
        running: false,
        value: 0
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.state.running) {
      this.timer = setInterval(
        () => this.forceUpdate(),
        this.props.interval | 0
      );
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.state.running) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
  }

  saveChanges(state) {
    console.log("saveChanges", this.props.localStorage, state);
    if (this.props.localStorage) {
      localStorage.setItem(this.props.localStorage, JSON.stringify(state));
    }
    return state;
  }

  start = () => {
    const now = Date.now();

    this.setState(({ running, value }) => {
      if (running) return null;

      this.timer = setInterval(
        () => this.forceUpdate(),
        this.props.interval | 0
      );

      return this.saveChanges({
        running: true,
        value: value - now
      });
    });
  };

  stop = () => {
    const now = Date.now();

    this.setState(({ running, value }) => {
      if (!running) return null;

      clearInterval(this.timer);
      return this.saveChanges({
        running: false,
        value: value + now
      });
    });
  };

  reset = () => {
    const now = Date.now();

    this.setState(({ running, value }) => {
      return this.saveChanges({
        running: false,
        value: 0
      });

      //just reset the timer to 0, don' stop it
      //return this.saveChanges({
      //  running,
      //  value: running? -now: 0
      //});
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      start, stop, reset,
      state: { running, value }
    } = this;

    const timestamp = running ? Date.now() + value : value;
    const h = Math.floor(timestamp / 3600000);
    const m = Math.floor(timestamp / 60000) % 60;
    const s = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000) % 60;
    const ms = timestamp % 1000;

    const _ = (nr, length = 2, padding = 0) =>
      String(nr).padStart(length, padding);

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h2 className="text-center"> React Based Timer </h2>
        <div className="timer-container">
          <div className="current-timer">
            {_(h) + ":" + _(m) + ":" + _(s) + "." + _(ms, 3)}
          </div>
          <div className="timer-controls">
            <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={start}>
              Start Timer
            </button>

            <button className="btn btn-alert" onClick={stop}>
              Stop Timer
            </button>

            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={reset}>
              Reset!
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

check this Sandbox out

[image: Edit xpp1wrmmqp]